# Como faço o egrep printar a lista de matchs de um arquivo?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Eu estou lendo um livro de *regular expressions* em que o autor utiliza `egrep` para mostrar alguns exemplos. Ocorre que quando tento replicar os exemplos no meu computador meu output fica diferente do apresentado no livro. No meu caso, o output do `egrep` é o texto completo, com os matchs da regex destacados em vermelho. Por outro lado, o autor, que usa o mesmo comando, tem como output a lista de matchs.

Exemplo:

```
egrep '\bS[a-z]+' bezos.txt
```

Output:

```
Bezos was born Jeffrey Preston Jorgensen in Albuquerque, New Mexico, on January 12, 1964, the son of Jacklyn (née Gise) and Ted Jorgensen.[9] At the time of his birth, his mother was a 17-year-old high school student and his father was a bike shop owner.[10] After his parents divorced, his mother married Cuban immigrant Miguel "Mike" Bezos in April 1968.[11] Shortly after the wedding, Mike adopted four-year-old Jorgensen, whose surname was then changed to Bezos.[12] The family moved to Houston, Texas, where Mike worked as an engineer for Exxon after he received a degree from the University of New Mexico.[13] Bezos attended River Oaks Elementary School in Houston from fourth to sixth grade.[14] Bezos's maternal grandfather was Lawrence Preston Gise, a regional director of the U.S. Atomic Energy Commission (AEC) in Albuquerque.[15] Gise retired early to his family's ranch near Cotulla, Texas, where Bezos would spend many summers in his youth.[13] Bezos would later purchase this ranch and expand it from 25,000 acres (10,117 ha) to 300,000 acres (121,406 ha).[16][17] His maternal grandmother was Mattie Louise Gise (née Strait), through whom he is a cousin of country singer George Strait.[18]
```

No output as palvras **Shorlty**, **School** e **Strait** aparecem no terminal em vermelho.

O mesmo comando, no livro, teria o seguinte output:

```
Shortly
School
Strait
```

Como faço para printar apenas a lista de matchs, como no livro, e não o texto inteiro?

**P.S:** No livro, o autor usa uma arquivo de extensão `list`. Talvez isso ajude a explicar a diferença no output, mas nunca vi essa extensão de arquivo antes, por isso fiquei em dúvida se era extensão mesmo ou apenas o nome de exemplo do arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), basta usar a opção `-o` ou `--only-matching`:

```
egrep -o '\bS[a-z]+' bezos.txt
egrep --only-matching '\bS[a-z]+' bezos.txt
```

Esta opção é descrita como:

> -o, --only-matching
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Ou seja, imprime apenas o trecho da string que corresponde ao *match* (em vez da linha inteira), sendo que cada trecho encontrado estará em uma linha.

---

Só um detalhe, testando com essa linha que está na pergunta, foi retornado `Strait` duas vezes, já que esta palavra ocorre duas vezes na linha.

E meu palpite é que o livro *provavelmente* setou a variável `GREP_OPTIONS`, na qual você pode colocar opções *default* para serem usadas no `grep`/`egrep`. Por exemplo, se eu fizer:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="-o"
```

Eu posso rodar o `egrep` sem a opção `-o`, que o comando será rodado com esta opção, pois é o que está indicado na variável.

Ou então o livro definiu um `alias`:

```
alias egrep="egrep -o"
```

Comment: Ah sim. Muito interessante sua hipótese sobre o alias. Deve ter ocorrido isso mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: @Lucas O `alias` ou `GREP_OPTIONS` são as 2 formas que imagino pra isso acontecer. Talvez ele tenha feito isso em algum capítulo anterior, não sei...